# How to change construct to change name of the folder with Jquery UploadHandler in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, model-view-controller, upload

i have a problem with uploading file using UploadHandler Jquery. I changed name of the default folder in construct, but in another function i also want that file was saved in another folder but keep the first folder. So i want to change that name of the folder (from **images/banner** to **images/slide**) with parameter but i can't do that. Some body can help me! This is my code!
I used this Plugin from: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
and class UploadHandler.php: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

In UploadHandler.php:

```
public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/images/banner/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/images/banner/',
            'input_stream' => 'php://input',
            'user_dirs' => false,
            'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
            // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
            'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
            'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
                'OPTIONS',
                'HEAD', ........
```

And i try change it in controllers:

```
public function uploadProductFile()
    {
        $options = array(
            'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/slide/',
            'upload_url' => base_url() . '/images/slide/'
            );
        $uploadProductFile = new UploadHandler($options);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code snippets that you provided how `__construct` is using `$options` argument. Either that is the problem or you need to provide more details on how that argument is processed so that someone could help you out. If `UploadHandler` is not your code, then you should better explain/link where it's coming from since maybe you're integrating 3rd party code/plugin incorrectly.

Comment: thank you. i edited my question. have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to upload this file, before it can upload but it uploaded in the folder of controllers. And i don't see them. So i change the file directory to images folder like this:

```
public function uploadProductFile()
    {
        $options = array(
            'upload_dir' => dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/images/slide/',
            'upload_url' => base_url() . '/images/slide/'
            );
        $uploadProductFile = new UploadHandler($options);
    }
```

My folder tree (mvc):

```
application
|
images
|
...
```